# How do I close an IF statement if there is no more code to be executed with 'else'?

Tags: c#

In my beginners secret word game, Assuming the game is finished but there is more unrelated code to follow, is ending the final if statement with 'else {}'(as at the end of my code) the best way to move on to whatever code follows? or does whatever follows on after this need to be contained within the else's {}? Total beginner, criticism welcome!

```
        string secretWord = "Catatonic";
        string guess = "";
        int guessCount = 0;
        int guessLimit = 3;
        bool outOfGuesses = false;
        bool firstGuess = false;

        Console.WriteLine("Guess the secret word: ");
            guess = Console.ReadLine();
        guessCount++;
        if (guess == secretWord)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You win!");
            firstGuess = true;  
        }
        else

            do
                if (guessCount < guessLimit)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Wrong answer, try again: ");
                    guess = Console.ReadLine();
                    guessCount++;
                }
                else
                {
                    outOfGuesses = true;
                } while (guess != secretWord && !outOfGuesses);

                if (guess != secretWord && outOfGuesses)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You're out of guesses mate");
        }
        else if (!firstGuess)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You're a winner!");
        }
        else {}
```

Comment: When the game is finished, you can simply `return` so no need to wrap all the below code in another else part

Comment: I would recommend writing down the "flow" of your logic on paper before programming. The program you are trying to achieve could be much simpler when using loops and conditionals in a correct way which can be achieved by writing down the flow.

Comment: else {} is superfluous, you don't need it at all.

Answer (score 6):

An `if` or an `else` is followed by a single statement or by one or more statements inside a code block, `{ }`.

Forget about the single statement and always use `{}` and you only have to learn 1 pattern:

```
 if (a == b)
 {
    // code for a == b
 }
 else
 {
    // code for a != b
 }
```

The `else { }` part is optional.

The same advice goes for `do while`, always use `{}` :

```
do
{
   // code to repeat   
}
while(x < y)
```

Answer (score 1):

As well as the previous good advice, also try using `string.Equals` so that you can make it case insensitive if you need to (or not!)

Also, you can simplify the logic a little, you don't need to check for firstGuess:

```
        string secretWord = "Catatonic";
        string guess = "";
        int guessCount = 0;
        int guessLimit = 3;
        bool outOfGuesses = false;

        Console.WriteLine("Guess the secret word: ");
        do
        {
            guess = Console.ReadLine();
            guessCount++;
            if (string.Equals(guess, secretWord, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(guessCount == 1 ? "You win!" : "You're a winner!");
                break;
            }

            if (guessCount < guessLimit)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Wrong answer, try again: ");
            }
            else
            {
                outOfGuesses = true;
            }

        } while (!outOfGuesses);

        if (outOfGuesses)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You're out of guesses mate");
        }
```

Comment: You can find good advice on `Do` loops here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/do and `If` statements here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/if-else